# I am currently install "npm install --save dev webpack webpack-dev-server" but I face the issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, webpack-dev-server

When I am run the command after some process it's got this error

```
 "npm install --save dev webpack webpack-dev-server"
```

```
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for inotify@1.4.6: wanted {"os":"linux"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    linux
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  undefined
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

Comment: You forgot the dash ( - ) between `--save-dev`

Answer (score 3):

The right command is

```
npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with no `--save-dev` typos, deleting my "package-lock.json" and re-running npm install worked